# LogonUser and others return error 1337 in Windows Server 2003 x86

Tags: windows, security, winapi, impersonation

After some update, I see following issue on all Windows Server 2003 member servers (x86 only): LogonUser, and LogonUserEx calls are failing with error 1337 (The security ID structure is invalid).

Basically, following code fails:

```
HANDLE token;
BOOL b = LogonUserA( "username", "DOMAIN", "password", 
           LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token );
```

I also noticed following

- Running same LogonUser code as localsystem works ok
- Running this code on Windows Server 2003 unpatched for a long time works fine
- After latest patches, WS2003 x86 fails, GetLastError() returns 1337
- Configuring “act as part of operating system” privilege does not help. Neither does enabling SE_TCB_NAME privilege explicitly in the code.
- Runas /user:DOMAIN\username works ok, whether computer is patched or not

Have anybody ran into the same problem? Have Microsoft recognized it as a bug?

Is there a workaround? Since runas is working, I assume there is an alternative way to do what LogonUser does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was something in the product I'm developing that caused such behavior, not a windows bug.

From `WinError.h`:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_INVALID_SID
//
// MessageText:
//
// The security ID structure is invalid.
//
#define ERROR_INVALID_SID                1337L
```

Comment: Seeing error 1337 always makes me think someone is trying to be funny.

Comment: Ditto - someone's not leet enough :p

Comment: I know what one might think about this error, but that REALLY was something corrupting the SID structure, believe it or not

Comment: i'm curious what you could possibly be doing to present a corrupted sid structure. `LogonUser` doesn't even *take* a security identifier!

Comment: @Ian Boyd the application I have been working with (auditing software) used code injection into lsass to monitor for the logons, and there was a bug in that code, which caused SID to corrupt under some circumstances.